# Как можно узнать, над каким элементом премещаемый элемент?

Tags: javascript

Как можно узнать при перемещении элемента, над каким элементом перемещаемый элемент находится?

`onmouseover` не работает, потому что перетаскиваемый элемент закрывает другие элементы.

Comment: Есть простой и верный способ: Размещайте перетаскиваемый элемент рядом с курсором

Answer (score 2):

Если вы работаете с [jQuery UI Droppable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#accepted-elements), то этого можно достичь с помощью события `dropover`:

```
$(".dropable").bind("dropover", function (event, ui) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: нет, я не работаю с jQuery, хочу всё это реализовать при помощи javascript.

Comment: Тогда уберите тег jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте узнать по координатам положения курсора.

Comment: как это сделать?

если не трудно, приведите пример.

Comment: Ну, раз вы уже перемещаете элементы, то можете просто посчитать координаты и размеры контейнеров и при движении курсора проверять, над каким из контейнеров находится курсор.

Comment: Координаты элемента от верхнего левого угла документа?

Comment: Зависит от стилей перетаскиваемого элемента. Если position:fixed, придется считать от угла экрана.